# Excel - Create a new row everytime their is a new row on the other sheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I've got two worksheets on Google sheets. One is automatically populated with new rows from the results of a Google Form its attached to. The second sheet in the document has been created by me. It has a formula on each row which checks for values in rows in sheet 1.

When a new row is added automatically in sheet 1, sheet 2 does not automatically create a row, because it doesn't know it should. A the moment I am simply highlighting the above row, and dragging it down to copy across the previous row with formulas.

My question is: is it possible to AUTOMATICALLY have a new row created on sheet 2 when a new row is created on sheet 1?

**Sheet 1 (Responses): Row A2 - currently created automatically

Sheet 2 (Question Scores): Row A2 - currently created manually**

The formula in each cell (Sheet 2: A9 for example) of the rows is currently the following:

```
=LEN(Responses!B9)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(Responses!B9,"~",""))
```

The Google Sheet file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/u41d3zjzr7rgwfy/Contact%20Centre%20Customer%20Experience%20Checklist%20%28Responses%29.xlsx?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Does this formula work as you want in cell B2 on Sheet2 (you will need to remove the existing contents of column B before pasting it in):

`=ArrayFormula(IF(Responses!B2:B="",,LEN(Responses!B2:B)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(Responses!B2:B,"~",""))))`

Comment: No, coming up with #NAME? in the cell instead, and the error "The formula contains unrecognised text". I've added a link to the actual file via dropbox in my question if it would be of help to see things.

Comment: The Arrayformula function will only work in the original Google response sheet.  It looks like this file is a downloaded copy in .xlsx format, which will not recognise it.